# Getting a table search function to work correctly?

Tags: swift, search, uisearchbar

I am trying to get a search bar working for my table that shows JSON data. here is my search bar function:

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    filtered = arrRes.filter({ (text) -> Bool in
        let tmp: NSString = text
        let range = tmp.rangeOfString(searchText, options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch)
        return range.location != NSNotFound
    })
    if(filtered.count == 0){
        searchActive = false;
    } else {
        searchActive = true;
    }
    self.exercisesTableView.reloadData()
```

and here is my declared variable to store the data

```
    var arrRes: [[NSObject: AnyObject]] = []
```

I am pulling the error:

> Cannot invoke 'filter' with an argument list of type '(([NSObject : AnyObject]) throws -> Bool) Expected an argument list of type '((Dictionary) throws -> Bool)''

Im sure this is to do with accessing the arrRes variable and its datatypes but im unsure of how to solve it?

Thanks for any insight

Comment: How is there `filtered` variable declared?

Comment: its in the code in the OP:     filtered = arrRes.filter({ (text) -> Bool in

Comment: You're setting it there, but where is it declared? It looks like the problem is related to a type mismatch between this and the output of the `filter`, so it would help to know the type of the `filtered` variable.

Comment: From the error the type must be '((Dictionary) throws -> Bool)''. where as the passed in arrRes is (([NSObject : AnyObject]) throws -> Bool). It wants a dictionary but my arrRes data variable is an Array. So i assume i need to do some conversion somewhere but thats where im stuck

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you just need to update your declaration of `filtered` to match `arrRes`, like so:

```
var filtered: [[NSObject: AnyObject]] = []
```

...but it's difficult to know for sure without knowing how that variable is currently declared.

Comment: variable currently declared as var filtered:[String] = [], however if i changed it to your stated type from a String, i loose parts of the function that require a string datatype such as let tmp: NSString = text and             let range = tmp.rangeOfString(searchText, options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch). I assume the better route would be to make arrRes variable a dictionary of strings instead somehow?

Comment: That will depend on what you are trying to do and what that `arrRes` variable contains.

Comment: how would i go about working that out? I get that i cant filter arrRes into filtered unless they match, but if i make them match, they arent String types, they are NSObject: AnyObject, it seems so it breaks my SearchBar function and i cant use them as labels for the cell rows either!

Comment: You want to map an `[NSObject: AnyObject]` on to a `String`. You need to understand what that dictionary contains and how to get a `String` out of it. I can't help you with that without more information.